# On finite capable $p$-group of class two

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, gap, p-groups

Do there exists a finite capable $p$-group  $G$ of class two with cyclic center and the center is not subgroup of Frattini subgroup of $G$?

A group $G$ is capable if there exists a group $H$ such that $G\cong\dfrac{H}{Z(H)}$.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest examples have order $256$ and there are a few of those.
For example, for $H=\textrm{SmallGroup}(256,4509)$, we have $H/Z(H)=G\cong \textrm{SmallGroup}(64,91)$ and $G$ has cyclic center of order $4$ which intersects the Frattini subgroup of $G$ in a subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: $\textrm{SmallGroup}(64,91)$ is of class 3.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that requirement.

Comment: There is no example $H$ of order $512$ or less.